# Vehicle wont turn over, thinking its the AC clutch

Tags: ford, ac, belt, expedition

I have a 2010 Ford Expedition that wont turn over even with a full charge, jump pack, and a jump to a heavy duty 350.  Before it went out, there was a constant metal grinding sound, like a broken bearing, which someone told me was the A/C clutch.  I'd like to get this vehicle running, can I just take off the belt to get it going?  How would you recommend troubleshooting this?

Comment: You can always take the belt off and try, but I highly doubt the A/C is causing this issue. There has to be two things which would keep compressor from allowing this to happening: 1) The compressor would have to be seized; 2) The clutch on the compressor would also have to be seized. If there bearing was bad, this might happen, but more than likely you'd just hear a bunch of noise and it wouldn't be seized. Put a breaker bar with proper socket on the crankshaft bolt and see if it will turn. Are you even hearing any noise out of the starter when you turn the key? Should at least be a big clunk.

Comment: BTW ... Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)

Comment: Thanks! I looked but the serpentine looks to be the only belt there.

Comment: Yeah its clunking but not turning over, the battery is now likely shot as well

Comment: Can you slip the serpentine off and hand-turn the AC pulley?

Comment: The mechanic tried to hand turn the AC pulley and found that was the problem, thanks!